# How To Get the Current Size of a UIImage During Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiviewanimation

I have an image (innerCircle) that is growing and shrinking in scale with an animation using the following:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay:0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.innerCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.5, 3.5)
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.innerCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

I am trying to get the **current** size of the image at any point during the animation so that I can check when it grows beyond a certain point. I want to do this so I can change a label of text from "Inhale" to "Exhale" and visa-versa.

I have tried using

```
let innerCircleWidth = self.innerCircle.image!.size.width
```

but that only gets the initial width value. It does not update.

Many thanks!

Comment: You should look at the presentation layer of `innerCircle`. `innerCircle.layer.presentationLayer()?.frame`

Comment: "I am trying to get the current size of the image at any point during the animation so that I can check when it grows beyond a certain point. I want to do this so I can change a label of text from "Inhale" to "Exhale" and visa-versa" That is totally the wrong approach. You should build the change from Inhale to Exhale _into the animation_ — not try to watch the animation and interfere with it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `UIView.animateWithDuration` to get accurate information about what is currently being displayed you should check the `presentationLayer` of the view(s) that's animating, in your case `innerCircle.layer.presentationLayer()?.frame` not the view's frame itself. For more information about this you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/236/).

To get a sense for how this works you can place the following code in a swift playground.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let outerCircle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000))
let innerCircle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100, height: 100))
outerCircle.addSubview(innerCircle)
innerCircle.center = outerCircle.center
innerCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay:0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: { () -> Void in
    innerCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.5, 3.5)
}) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
        innerCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    })
}



class TimerObject: NSObject {
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.printPresentationFrame), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    }

    @objc func printPresentationFrame()
    {
        print(innerCircle.layer.presentationLayer()?.frame)
    }
}
let timerObject = TimerObject()

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = outerCircle
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the size of the image did not change. Applying a transform does not change the size of a view.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much, I am still new to this. Is there a way to get the current scale of the view so that I can accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Probably this would work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694785/get-size-of-uiview-after-applying-cgaffinetransform