# How to get the frame of a subview after CGAffineTransform?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, frame, cgaffinetransform

I have a view with many subviews.
After applying the following transform

```
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)];
```

I'm not able to get the updated frame of the subviews. 
When doing

```
CGRect frame = subview.frame;
```

It's always the original frame before transform.

How can I calculate the frame after the rotation ?

Many thanks,

Best

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get size of UIView after applying CGAffineTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694785/get-size-of-uiview-after-applying-cgaffinetransform)

Comment: It's not a dulicate as I don't want to get the size of the view after the transform but the frame of a subview inside the view

Comment: That should work the same way imo. (`... CGRect transformedBounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(subview.bounds, view.transform); ...`). No time to test and write an answer in the moment. Sorry.